# Unable to resolve dependency tree while installing ngx-datatable

Tags: html, angular, typescript, npm, ngx-datatable

I am trying to install the ngx-datatable module for my angular project. But whenever i try to install it with npm this error shows.

[image]

I tried doing `npm i @swimlane/ngx-datatable --force` and that installed the module but my whole project stopped working.

Comment: Looks like the `@swimlane/ngx-datatable` requires an earlier version of rxjs. You may have to use an earlier rxjs/angular version to run this package.

Comment: @MikeS. Can you tell me how to use an earlier version of rxjs

Comment: As I already said, you may have to downgrade your angular version in order to use an earlier version of rxjs. @angular/core has peer dependencies to rxjs, so you'll have to see which version works for the package you mentioned.